How can I block UDP connections from a specific IP using nftables?
I am experimenting using nftables on a Raspberry Pi and a Debian 12 system.
I am able to block TCP IP addresses as follows:
ip saddr 192.168.1.98 counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop 

The above will drop a TCP connections but not a UDP connection.
Can anyone explain how to block both?
Here is my current nttable.conf file (simple)
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

flush ruleset

table inet filter {
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority 0;
        ip protocol icmp counter accept comment "accept all ICMP types - this is a ping"
        ip saddr 192.168.1.98 counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop
        ip saddr 192.168.1.7 counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop 
        # accept any localhost traffic
        iif lo accept

        # accept traffic originated from us
        ct state established,related accept

        # activate the following line to accept common local services
        tcp dport { 22, 80, 443} ct state new accept
        udp dport {4711,25565,5353 ,59122 ,57324 ,631,19132 ,45091 } ct state new accept

        # ICMPv6 packets which must not be dropped, see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4890#section-4.4.1
        meta nfproto ipv6 icmpv6 type { destination-unreachable, packet-too-big, time-exceeded, parameter-problem, echo-reply, echo-request, nd-router-solicit, nd-router-advert, nd-neighbor-solicit, nd-neighbor-advert, 148, 149 } accept
        ip6 saddr fe80::/10 icmpv6 type { 130, 131, 132, 143, 151, 152, 153 } accept
        

        # count and drop any other traffic
        counter drop
    }
    #from gentoo
    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority 0; policy drop;
        counter comment "count dropped packets"
    }

    # If you're not counting packets, this chain can be omitted.
    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
        counter comment "count accepted packets"
    }
}



Here is a rule that will work:
two rules:

ip saddr 192.168.1.98 tcp dport { 1-65535 } counter drop
ip saddr 192.168.1.98 udp dport { 1-65535 } counter drop

or one rule:

ip saddr 192.168.1.98 meta l4proto { tcp, udp } counter drop


You can use meta l4proto { tcp, udp } after the interface name or in your case, the ip saddr ... field, and before the counter or any port specification.
This will specify both TCP and UDP connection types in the same rule.

Except that would only "narrow down" the rule. In other words, "by default" a rule does not match only TCP traffics, but traffics of any protocol.
